# Is ".ad-space" a reserved class in webkit?

Tags: html, css, webkit

Take a look at this, I'm using 960.gs here and couldn't figure out why my ads class named ".ad-space" was disappearing in webkit. Seems to work in Firefox, but not in Chrome or Safari. Is it an addon bug in webkit? Maybe Adblock Plus? Anyone else notice the bottom one isn't there? It doesn't seem to happen in local development, but when http:// is used it disappears.

Comment: Yep, that's all it is. Adblock plus interference. Moral of the story: don't name your ad's class "ad-space".

Comment: You can post your comment as an answer, and later come back and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Adblock plus interference. Moral of the story: don't name your ad's class "ad-space"